# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined VueJS

Tags: stripe-payments, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

In Laravel 5.4 I am trying to make a payment with Stripe. I am following the video on laracast if you have an account you can watch the video here:
https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe/episodes/3

I changed it up to fit my needs and there are somethings he does that does not work with version 0.3 of vue which I was able to fix except for this problem.

I have this code:

```
data: function data() {
  return {
     stripeEmail: '',
     stripeToken: ''
  };
},
created: function created() {

  this.stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({

    key: "my_key",
    image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
    locale: "auto",
    token: (token) => {
      this.stripeToken = token.id;
      this.stripeEmail = token.email;

      this.$http.post('/payment', this.$data).then(response => alert('Message'));
    }
  });
},


methods: {
  buy: function buy() {
    this.stripe.open({
      name: "One Month Subscription",
      description: "Having your business displayed for one month.",
      zipcode: true,
      amount: 1000

    });
  }
}
```

I am able to put the information in but as soon as I hit submit it returns the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

I installed vue-resource in my bootstrap.js here:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');
```

This solved the $http problem but now I get the post problem.

If there is any other information you need let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be a problem with `this`.  Specifically, the `this` in `created` is likely not the same as the `this` in `token`.  Try ... this:

```
created: function created() {
  var self = this;

  self.stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "my_key",
    image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
    locale: "auto",
    token: (token) => {
      self.stripeToken = token.id;
      self.stripeEmail = token.email;

      self.$http.post('/payment', self.$data).then(response => alert('Message'));
    }
  });
},
```

I know you're using arrow functions so this shouldn't be the case, but I'd give it a try anyways and see how it goes.

Comment: Did you add some debugging `console.log()` statements to figure out why?  What is the value of `self.$http`?

This is something you're going to have to step through to debug; there's not likely to be an obvious answer here unfortunately.